# Wrapping an iOS app with XenMobile failing

Tags: ios, mdm, word-wrap, citrix

We have an iOS business application that is released successfully on the iTunes store.

One of our clients wants to deploy our app on their Citrix XenMobile internal store.

We have been able to wrap the MDX ourselves and give it to them and they can put it on their store, however, when they attempt to install it fails.  This is the log.

```
Payload/PS|Software.app
Jul  3 13:54:51 Freds-iPad installd[61] <Error>: 0x3c5000 install_application: Could not preflight application install
Jul  3 13:54:51 Freds-iPad itunesstored[92] <Error>: 0x1caf000 MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices: failed with -1
Jul  3 13:54:51 Freds-iPad itunesstored[92] <Warning>: ERROR: MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices returned nil
Jul  3 13:54:51 Freds-iPad lsd[70] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installation failed for app com.developers.software
Jul  3 13:54:51 Freds-iPad itunesstored[92] <Warning>: LaunchServices: install    PhaseFinishedForProgress: com.developers.software.Installing -<NSProgress: phase=Installing; state=Failed; fractionCompleted=0.000000> called, removing progress from cache
Jul  3 13:54:51 Freds-iPad lsd[70] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installation failed for app com.developers.software
Jul  3 13:54:51 Freds-iPad itunesstored[92] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: com.developers.software.Loading - <NSProgress: phase=Loading; state=Failed; fractionCompleted=1.000000> called, removing progress from cache
Jul  3 13:54:51 Freds-iPad installd[61] <Error>: 0x3c5000 handle_install_for_ls: API failed
```

We've searched for these messages and can't find anything conclusive that tells us what we're doing wrong.  We do not have a local XenMobile installation so cannot test locally.

It is our understanding that we do not need an Apple Enterprise license; we do have a Developers license.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

Create the IPA using the iOS developers team provisioning profile and have the customer wrap it into an MDX using their Apple Enterprise provisioning profile.